# Resolving the dreaded "an attempt was made to access a token that does not exist" in Win7 64-bit?

Tags: windows-7, uac, certificate, trusted-root-certificates

I attempted to access "Control Panel -> System and Security -> Administrative Tools -> Local Security Policy" today and received the error:

```
"an attempt was made to access a token that does not exist"
```

I'm running as an administrative user, and when I came across this error I was attempting to install Webroot's certificate as a trusted certificate so I could avoid the Blue UAC prompt I receive when my computer boots up and attempts to run webroot.  I'd rather it just run.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually I just ran `sfc /scannow` and now it works again...thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This may work for you also.
- Open a Command Prompt (CMD) in ELEVATED MODE (run as administrator)
- Navigate to %WINDIR%\System32 and re-register the required DLL files using the following command:

> For /F %s in ('dir /b *.dll') do regsvr32 /s %s

Comment: Welcome to superuser: This does not answer the question. Superuser is not a "Chat site" it is only a Q and A site. If you have a new question please ask it.  Please take a couple of minutes and read:- http://superuser.com/help .Answering: http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer, again welcome to superuser.Thankyou